# $R_1=\{(x,y) \in R^2:-1 \le x \le 1,-3 \le y \le 2 \}$ graph

Tags: relations

We have the following relation:
$R_1=\{(x,y) \in R^2:-1 \le x \le 1,-3 \le y \le 2 \}$
Could anyone tell me how to make the graph for the above relation?

Answer (score 0):

Literally translated, this says $R_1$ is the set of all points with $x$ and $y$ coordinates in the plane, such that the $x$ values range from $-1$ to $1$ and the $y$ values range from $-3$ to $2$. So the set is a rectangle, when drawn in regular Cartesian coordinates. Can you figure it out from there?